# Removing special characters and spaces from strings

Tags: r, string

```
name1 <- "Adam & Eve"
name2 <- "Spartacus"
name3 <- "Fitness and Health"
```

I want to remove all spaces and special characters such as `%&,.` and the word `and` between the names, and then capitalize each string, so the names become:

```
name1 <- "ADAMEVE"
name2 <- "SPARTACUS"
name3 <- "FITNESSHEALTH"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `sub` to remove the `and` string, then with `gsub` remove everything other (`^`) than the letters (upper, lower case) and convert the case to upper (`toupper`)

```
f1 <- function(x) toupper(gsub("[^A-Za-z]", "", sub("and", "", x, fixed = TRUE)))
```

-testing

```
> f1(name1)
[1] "ADAMEVE"
> f1(name2)
[1] "SPARTACUS"
> f1(name3)
[1] "FITNESSHEALTH"
```

Comment: Without testing for word boundaries, this will also remove "and" that's part of a word. e.g. `f1("hands")` returns `"HS"`

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by akrun's answer we could create a function and apply it to the vectors:

```
library(stringr)
my_function <- function(x){
    x <- str_replace_all(x, "[^A-Za-z0-9]","")
    x <- toupper(x)
    x <- str_remove_all(x, "AND")
    return(x)
}

my_function(c(name1, name2,name3))
```

Output:

```
[1] "ADAMEVE"       "SPARTACUS"     "FITNESSHEALTH"
```

Comment: Same as another answer, without checking for word boundaries, this will remove "and" within other words

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stringr` with `str_remove_all()` and the patterns for "any non-word characters" (`"\\D"`), and the word  `"and"` (use word boundaries here, `\\b`), and then change all to upper case with `toupper()`

```
library(stringr)

name1 %>% str_remove_all("\\D|\\band\\b") %>% toupper
```

If you want do define a function for that, you can do it as follows:

```
my_function <- function(x) { x %>% str_remove_all ("\\D|\\band\\b") %>% toupper }
```